# Paypal: print the values returned by paypal

Tags: php, paypal

I want to print the values returned by paypal notify_url

```
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="notifyurl.php" />
```

I want to see the variables returned by paypl to notifyurl.php

I have written a code in notifyurl.php to insert the values returned by paypal to database but it's not working. I want to use print_r($_POST) to see the variables returned by paypal, where do I use this. I used  print_r($_POST) in notifyurl.php but it's no use.

```
<input type='hidden' name='return' value='returnurl.php'>
```

The return url successfully redirects to the returnurl.php

Comment: Write the output to a log file.

Comment: Which of the product you are using. I used digital goods checkout as mentioned [here](https://devtools-paypal.com/integrationwizard/index.php) and it works properly